# How to update rows by Id

Tags: javascript, java, mysql, angularjs

I'm trying to update a row by its Id using Java mysql and angular js 
the problem is that I'm getting false and nothing is changing in the database

Here is my java function :

```
public boolean modifierClient(int idclient, String nomcomplet, String mail,int numerocompte, String mdp) {
            try 
            {
                System.out.println("Edition du client avec le nom complet: " + idclient);
                Connection con = Connexion.getConnection();

             // L'insert avec mysql
                String query = " UPDATE client SET nomcomplet = ?, mail = ?, numerocompte = ?, mdp = ? WHERE idclient = ?";

                PreparedStatement ps = con.prepareStatement(query);
                ps.setInt(1, idclient);
                ps.setString (2, nomcomplet);
                ps.setString (3, mail);
                ps.setInt (4, numerocompte);
                ps.setString (5, mdp);

                ps.executeUpdate();
                if(ps.executeUpdate() > 0) {
                    return true;

                }
                else 
                {
                    return false;
                }
            }

            catch (Exception e) 
            {
                    System.out.println("Erreur avec modifierClient() -->" + e.getMessage());
                    return false;
            }
        }
```

Here is my controller function :

```
    @POST
        @Path("modifierClient/{idclient}/{nomcomplet}/{mail}/{numerocompte}/{mdp}")
        @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
        @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
        public boolean modifierClient(@PathParam("idclient") int idclient, @PathParam("nomcomplet") String nomcomplet, @PathParam("mail") String mail,@PathParam("numerocompte") int numerocompte, @PathParam("mdp") String mdp) {
                 ClientDao dao = new ClientDao();
             return dao.modifierClient(idclient,nomcomplet,mail,numerocompte,mdp);
        }
```

and my angular js function :

```
$http.post('rest/client/modifierClient/'+idclient+'/'+$scope.fullname+'/'+$scope.mail+'/'+$scope.numcompte+'/'+$scope.mdp).then(function(data){
                    alert('modified  '+data.data);

                })
```

I need your help, thank you.

Comment: Don't call `ps.executeUpdate()` twice for the same query.

Comment: `ps.setInt(1, idclient);` but this should be `ps.setInt(5, idclient);` You have mixed your parameter index ... It depends on the order from left to right in the `String` defined.

Comment: @AxelH Thank you that helped me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not using the correct index in your `PreparedStatement`. See the index used in the below code

```
String query = " UPDATE client SET nomcomplet = ?, mail = ?, numerocompte = ?, mdp = ? WHERE idclient = ?";

PreparedStatement ps = con.prepareStatement(query);

ps.setString (1, nomcomplet);
ps.setString (2, mail);
ps.setInt (3, numerocompte);
ps.setString (4, mdp);

ps.setInt(5, idclient);
```

The index value depends of the order you defined in the query.

Note : You should get an exception since you are trying to do `idClient = "apassword"` but `idClient` seems to be a numeric. The DB should tell you that you can't compare a varchar with a numeric

Answer (score -1):

Change your code as below

```
 ps.setString (1, nomcomplet);
 ps.setString (2, mail);
 ps.setInt (3, numerocompte);
 ps.setString (4, mdp);
 ps.setInt(5, idclient);

 int rowsAffected = ps.executeUpdate();

 if( rowsAffected  > 0) {
     return true;
 }
 else {
     return false;
 }
```